# Why is my attempt at a 'Quick Sort' not sorting properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, quicksort

I have been working hard to produce a 'simple' quick sort algorithm, as so many of the online examples seem to be written more complexly than perhaps required to demonstrate the mechanics of the algorithm.

I have got to a point where I cannot see why the final list is not sorting properly. I would be grateful for a set of fresh eyes and a pointer in the right direction to finish the code.

Here is my current code:

```
def qsort(dataset):

    if len(dataset) < 2:
        return (dataset)
    else:
        point1 = 0
        point2 = len(dataset) - 1
        pivot = (len(dataset) - 1 ) // 2

        while point1 != pivot and point2 != pivot:

            while dataset[point1] <= dataset[pivot] and point1 != pivot:
                point1 = point1 + 1
            while dataset[point2] >= dataset[pivot] and point2 != pivot:
                point2 = point2 - 1
            x = dataset[point1]
            dataset[point1] = dataset[point2]
            dataset[point2] = x


        left = qsort(dataset[0:pivot])
        right = qsort(dataset[(pivot+1):len(dataset)])

        return left + [dataset[pivot]] + right

dataset = [45, 29, 56, 23, 55, 27, 43, 46]

print(qsort(dataset))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

****EDIT**** new code after @Marko Mahnič suggestion but still not sorting correctly. I would be so grateful for any more help that can be offered.

```
def qsort(dataset):

    if len(dataset) < 2:
        return (dataset)
    else:
        point1 = 0
        point2 = len(dataset) - 1
        pivot = (len(dataset) - 1 ) // 2

        while point1 < point2:

            while dataset[point1] <= dataset[pivot] and point1 < point2:
                point1 = point1 + 1
            while dataset[point2] >= dataset[pivot] and point2 > point1:
                point2 = point2 - 1
            x = dataset[point1]
            dataset[point1] = dataset[point2]
            dataset[point2] = x


        left = qsort(dataset[0:pivot])
        right = qsort(dataset[(pivot+1):len(dataset)])

        return left + [dataset[pivot]] + right

dataset = [45, 29, 56, 23, 55, 27, 43, 46]

print(qsort(dataset))
```

Comment: There's no real reason to leave the pivot point out of the recursion. `qsort(d[:pivot]) +  qsort([pivot:])` would give you the same answer, assuming your partitioning is correct.

Comment: What is the smallest dataset that desn't sort correctly? Why? At what point (step through it with a debugger or output state) does it not behave correctly any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quicksort is normally an in-place sort, it sorts the original array instead of returning a sorted copy of the original array. The question's example code is a variation of Hoare partition version of quicksort. Hoare partition splits a partition into elements <= pivot, and elements >= pivot. Elements == to pivot and/or the pivot can end up anywhere, but this isn't an issue, and there is no need to track where the pivot ends up. The run time will generally be less if there are duplicates.

Example standard quicksort with Hoare partition method

```
def qsort(a, lo, hi):
    if(lo >= hi):
        return
    p = a[(lo + hi) / 2]        # pivot, any a[] except a[hi]
    i = lo - 1
    j = hi + 1
    while(1):
        while(1):               # while(a[++i] < p)
            i += 1
            if(a[i] >= p):
                break
        while(1):               # while(a[--j] < p)
            j -= 1
            if(a[j] <= p):
                break
        if(i >= j):
            break
        a[i],a[j] = a[j],a[i]
    qsort(a, lo, j)
    qsort(a, j+1, hi)

dataset = [45, 29, 56, 23, 55, 27, 43, 46]
qsort(dataset, 0, len(dataset)-1)   # last param is len-1
print(dataset)
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions should be `point1 < point2`, not `pointX != pivot`. The split to left and right should be where point1 and point2 meet.

Note that in qsort the important part of the pivot is its value, not its index. You can choose the value of any element from `dataset` as the pivot. When partitioning is done the elements left of `pivot2` will be lower or equal to the pivot's value and the elements right of `pivot1` will be higher or equal to the pivot's value.

You can adjust `pivot1` and `pivot2` before the recursive call so that the `left` array contains only the elements lower than the pivot, the `middle` array contains the elements with the pivot's value and the `right` array contains the elements higher than the pivot's value. This is a slight optimization. The result is then `left + middle + right`. This is especially useful when `dataset` has duplicated elements.

These changes will make your algorithm correct but not optimal. The problem is that the algorithm is making copies of parts of the original list which requires `O(n^2)` extra space which is `(n-1)*(n-2)/2` in the worst case when it selects the highest or the lowest value as the pivot. So instead of sorting full lists, the algorithm should be changed to sort part of the list in-place. Its interface should be changed to:

```
def qsort( a, left, right ):
```

and the recursive calls should be:

```
qsort( a, left, pivot2 )
qsort( a, pivot1, right )
```

Another optimization is to reduce the number of recursive calls since they are not cheap. When the size of the input list falls below a certain small value (8 for example), the list can be sorted with a simpler `O(n^2)` sorting algorithm like Simple Insertion, Simple Selection, Bubble Sort or similar.

Comment: Thank you, you are right with the logic but it doesn't seem to work. I have edited my question to show the altered code so you can double check I have done what you suggested correctly. If you could provide a solution I would be so grateful.

Comment: @sw12345: You are still splitting the array on the pivot's index instead of the last value of `pivot1` and/or `pivot2`. Note that in qsort the important part of the pivot is its value, not its index. You can choose the value of any element from `dataset` as the pivot. When partitioning is done the elements left of `pivot2` will be lower or equal to the pivot's value and the elements right of `pivot1` will be higher or equal to the pivot's value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an iterative version of your algorithm. It uses a stack to eliminate the need for the recursive calls. Using the last element as the pivot makes it simpler too:

```py
def qsort(dataset):
    low = 0
    high = len(dataset) - 1

    # stack tio use instead of the stack of recursive function calls
    stack = [0] * len(dataset)
    top = -1

    # stack initial values
    top += 1
    stack[top] = low
    top += 1
    stack[top] = high

    # while the stack is not empty
    while top >= 0:

        # pop high and low
        high = stack[top]
        top -= 1
        low = stack[top]
        top -= 1

        # partition by the pivot
        i = low - 1
        x = dataset[high]   # using the last element as pivot
        for j in range(low, high):
            if dataset[j] <= x:
                # increment index of smaller element
                i += 1
                dataset[i], dataset[j] = dataset[j], dataset[i]
        dataset[i + 1], dataset[high] = dataset[high], dataset[i + 1]
        p = i + 1   # updates the pivot position

        # If there are elements on left side of pivot,
        # then push left side to stack
        if p - 1 > low:
            top += 1
            stack[top] = low
            top += 1
            stack[top] = p - 1

        # If there are elements on right side of pivot,
        # then push right side to stack
        if p + 1 < high:
            top += 1
            stack[top] = p + 1
            top += 1
            stack[top] = high

    return dataset

dataset = [45, 29, 56, 23, 55, 27, 43, 46]

print(qsort(dataset))
```

And you could make it more readable by extracting the stack manipulation and the partitioning to separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have worked out the issue.

Everything was fine except for the fact that I was not updating the location of the pivot if it was indeed the value at the pivot that was swapped during an iteration. I therefore added a couple of flags in the event of the pivot being swapped and updated the pivot location after the swap before the next split occurred.

Here is the code if anyone is interested. Of course would love the flags etc to be more tidy if any of you have any ideas?

```
def qsort(dataset):

    pivotatp1 = False
    pivotatp2 = False

    if len(dataset) < 2:
        return (dataset)
    else:
        point1 = 0
        point2 = len(dataset) - 1
        pivot = (len(dataset) - 1 ) // 2
        while point1 != pivot and point2 != pivot:

            while dataset[point1] <= dataset[pivot] and point1 != pivot:
                point1 = point1 + 1
            while dataset[point2] >= dataset[pivot] and point2 != pivot:
                point2 = point2 - 1

            if pivot == point1:
                pivotatp1 = True
            if pivot == point2:
                pivotatp2 = True

            x = dataset[point1]
            dataset[point1] = dataset[point2]
            dataset[point2] = x

            if pivotatp1 == True:
                pivot = point2
            if pivotatp2 == True:
                pivot = point1

        left = qsort(dataset[0:pivot])
        right = qsort(dataset[(pivot+1):len(dataset)])

        return left + [dataset[pivot]] + right

dataset = [45, 29, 56, 23, 55, 27, 43, 46]

print(qsort(dataset))
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer. By choosing the last element as the pivot the partitioning can be simpler.

Comment: You don't have to change the pivot's index. Just remember its value before entering the `while` loop. As mentioned in my answer, the pivot's position is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a variation of Hoare partition scheme. There's no need to keep track of the pivot, it can end up anywhere and it is not an issue, as no elements should be excluded from recursion. This means that `right = qsort(dataset[(pivot):len(dataset)])` (pivot, not pivot+1, since pivot won't really be the index to the pivot), unlike the Lomuto scheme, where the pivot ends up in it's sorted position, and it is excluded from recursion.